# How do you detect a window appearing without focus?

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm using UI Automation with installation wizards, specifically the FocusChangedEvent to catch when new windows appear on the desktop so I can interact with the buttons and elements. However, I've found that this doesn't catch some windows.

For example, this one gets detected by the event handler when it pops up:
[FireFox Setup Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsVzJ.png)

But this one does not: [7-Zip Setup Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rja4D.png)

I'm not completely sure why this is, though I suspect it has to do with the type of window and perhaps the elements on it that don't get detected. I've also tried checking for a WindowOpenedEvent with no luck. Is there any other alternative that I've missed?

This is the code I have right now:

```
public void Startup()
    {
        Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnFocusChanged);
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
            WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, 
            AutomationElement.FromHandle(_process.MainWindowHandle),
            TreeScope.Subtree, 
            new AutomationEventHandler(OnFocusChanged));
    }
```

Edit: I'm exploring non-UI Automation ways to do this now. Looking at the  MainWindowHandle of the process I run doesn't always work because it often spawns a child process that is the one actually responsible for the UI, so the only way I can think of doing this right now is to check the MainWindowHandle of every child process.